# How to get list of running application list in Oreo?

Tags: android

I am building an application which will give the list of all the current running application with package name in android 8,i can easily get them up till 7 ,is there any way we can do the same for android 8 and above

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use UsageStatsManager instead, this is a workaround and requires user permission (also, it will not work on all devices), basically you can ask the OS for application details for the last 2 seconds. this is not a real time solution but it may good enough for your needs.